# How can I add a new cmake flag that can be set in cmakelists.txt file just like CMAKE_MFC_FLAG?

Tags: cmake, toolchain

I want to create a new Flag just like CMAKE_MFC_FLAG and which can be used in a toolchain file to add some parameters in according to the new flag. I tried many other things like Cache variable and Environment variables but nothing worked.

things I have tried :

```
set(CMAKE_NEW_FLAG "1.2345")
set(CMAKE_NEW_FLAG "Visible everywhere"
    CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE
)

 SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY MyGlobalProperty "MyGlobalPropertyValue")
 set(Var1 "This is variable 1" CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

and tried to read this using following code in toolchain :

```
message("${CMAKE_${_lang}_COMPILER_VERSION}")
message("CMAKE_NEW_FLAG : ${CMAKE_NEW_FLAG}")
GET_PROPERTY(MyLocalVariable GLOBAL PROPERTY MyGlobalProperty)
message("${MyLocalVariable}")
#set(Var1 "This is variable 1" CACHE INTERNAL "")
message("${Var1}")

get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
endforeach()
```

But am not able to read the variable set in cmakelists.txt file in the toolchain file and the cmake kitware native file.

i tried a lot of options but nothing worked. any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: The whole purpose of toolchain file is to be run **before** `CMakeLists.txt` and being transparent for it. You may define some function in toolchain and call it from `CMakeLists.txt`, but this looks suspicious in any case.

Comment: I have the flag CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT set in my cmake lists file below 
set(CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " ${_tV}") 

And in the toolchain file I have set CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT like below - string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " ${_tM}") 


But when I have a Ninja file created, I only get "_tM" and not "_tM _tV". The scope seems to be different in both

Comment: As you use `string(APPEND)` in your toolchain, why do not use the same construction in your `CMakeLists.txt` too? Rewriting initial flags with `set()` cleanly contradicts with the toolchain.

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. That worked :)

Comment: Tsyvarev, i am getting following error myandroidcompiler.exe: error: argument unused during compilation: '-nobuiltininc'
myandroidcompiler.exe: error: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. i tried removing these arguments too. but didn't have any luck. do you have any idea?

Comment: i asked the same question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987547/ninja-giving-error-while-executing