# Ninja giving error while executing

Tags: command-line, cmake, ninja

I have created Ninja file using Cmake. While I execute the ninja file it shows following command

```
cmd.exe /C "cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/libs && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/libs && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/res && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/android/res C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/res/ && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/src && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/android/src C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/src/ && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/assets && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/assets/ && cd C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build" && C:\mydir\Backup\dev\tp\bin\myandroidcompiler.exe  -std=c++11 -ffor-scope -fno-exceptions -pipe -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffast-math -pedantic -Werror -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wsign-promo -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Os -ftree-vectorize -g -fno-limit-debug-info -fborland-extensions -fborland-auto-refcount  -fexceptions -fcxx-exceptions -mstackrealign -fno-spell-checking -x c++ -std=c++11 -O0 -fmath-errno -nobuiltininc   -shared  -o libandroidcmakeexample.so CMakeFiles\androidcmakeexample.dir\src\main.cpp.obj -L=\usr\include  -LC:\Users\Public\Documents\Android\AndroidNDK-9c_x86\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include  -L"C:\Users\Public\DOCUME~1\ANDROI~1\Studio\20.0\CATALO~1\ANDROI~1\sources\cxx-stl\GNU-LI~1\4.8\libs\ARMEAB~1\include "  -LC:\Users\Public\Documents\Android\AndroidNDK-9c_x86\sources\android\native_app_glue -llog -landroid && cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/libs C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/libs/ && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && android update project -t android-10 --name androidcmakeexample --path C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_directory C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/assets C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/android-cmake-example-discordia/build/apk/assets/ && cd /D C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\android-cmake-example-discordia\build\apk && ant debug""

myandroidcompiler.exe: error: argument unused during compilation: '-nobuiltininc'
myandroidcompiler.exe: error: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have tried removing this arguments as well. but this error persist. I have been stuck in this issue for past 2 days. any help would be highly appreciated.

When I checked CMakeoutput.log file it is having following text :

```
The target system is: ANDROID64 -  - 
The host system is: Windows - 10.0.15063 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/mydir/Backup/dev/tp/bin/bccaarm.exe 
Build flags: ;;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/android/native_app_glue;-I;c:/accolite/backup/dev/tp/include/android/fmx;;;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/android/native_app_glue;-I;c:/accolite/backup/dev/tp/include/android/fmx;;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include;-idirafter;C:/Android/android-ndk-r15c/sources/android/native_app_glue;-I;c:/accolite/backup/dev/tp/include/android/fmx;
```

Id flags: -c

The output was:
   0

in the Build flags i can see ; (semi-colon) is present in between of every spaces. is it expected? what am doing wrong?

Comment: `myandroidcompiler` - What is this? The error means that your project (or, more likely, a toolchain) adds an option (`-nobuiltininc`) which is incompatible with a mode in which a compiler is invoked. But you have provided information neither about a compiler nor about a toolchain.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, details about toolchain is at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986754/how-can-i-replicate-a-command-line-arguments-in-cmake-with-ninja. now am able to create the ninja and make files. but it is giving this error. am stuck

Comment: Please ask a self-contained question, including a minimal working example.

Comment: I have added CMakeoutput log in my question. why it is adding ; (semi-colons) at every spaces. is it expected behavior or is it the reason it is causing error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `-Qunused-arguments` compiler flag should silence these errors.
Try adding the following to your CMake command line:

`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-Qunused-arguments`

Or, in `CMakeLists.txt`:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Qunused-arguments")`

Comment: Thanks Valiano, Now that is coming as warning. but am stuck at other issue as below :  myandroidcompiler.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nobuiltininc'
myandroidcompiler.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'
ld: unknown option: --sysroot=C:/Users/Public/Documents/Android/AndroidNDK-9c_x86/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
myandroidcompiler.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. if you have any idea how i can proceed?